# Visual Studio 2010 crashes on Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-8.1

Visual Studio was working fine on Windows 8.
But has stopped working since the time I updated to Windows 8.1

Comment: Which processor are you using?

Comment: I am using an Intel (R) Core i5 - 3230 M CPU @ 2.60 GHz

Comment: are you using ms visual studio or visual c#?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intel 5000 HD drivers, download from below link and try:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23194